# Как подсчитать количество постов в разных категориях?

Tags: php

Доброе утро

Нужно в списке категорий, возле каждой категории, указать количество привязанных к ней постов. Мне кажется, что я нашёл решение, но не могу понять, как передать id категорий в модель.

Вот контроллер, где $pages — количество постов:

```
public function categoriesAction()
{
    // $pages = $this->model->pagesCount($this->route['id']);
    $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->categoriesCount(), 5);
    $vars = [
        'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
        'count' => $this->model->categoriesCount(),
        'list' => $this->model->categoriesList($this->route),
        'pages' => $this->model->pagesCount($this->route['id']),
    ];
    // $this->view->render('Список категорий', 0, 0, $vars, $pages);
    $this->view->render('Список категорий', 0, 0, $vars);
}
```

Счётчик:

```
public function pagesCount($id)
{
    $params = [
        'id' => $id,
    ];
    return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pages WHERE category = :id', $params);
}
```

Вывод в виде:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $val): ?>
    <li>Категория: <a href="/category/<?= $val['id'] ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($val['category'], ENT_QUOTES) ?></a> (<?= $pages ?>)</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

При попытке передачи id выдаёт незатейливое предупреждение:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home…
```

Comment: А вы обратитесь к элементу массива по индексу, которого в нём нет. Получите ровно такую же ошибку. Либо проверяйте, есть ли индекс в массиве, либо пользуйтесь оператором `??`

Comment: @ArchDemon как поступить в моём случае?

Comment: Метод ```$this->model->categoriesList()``` возвращает у вас список элементов у которых нет ключа ```id``` Проверьте указанный метод

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov ну почему же, есть:

`print_r($this->model->categoriesList($this->route));`

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [category] => Бактерии
            [dateadd] => 17.02.2023 13:10
            [datemod] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [category] => Вирусы
            [dateadd] => 17.02.2023 13:11
            [datemod] => 
        )`

Comment: Вот как-то надо передать все эти id в $this->model->categoriesCount() и по-сути, он должен посчитать и возвратить массив с количеством постов.

Comment: Вот так: `print_r($this->model->pagesCount($this->model->categoriesList(['id'])));` — ругается, что я пытаюсь передать массив как строку — `Array to string conversion in <b>/home/…` Как засунуть туда массив не соображу :(